# RadEditor ContentAreaMode DIV automatically sets focus on postback IE

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radeditor, telerik-editor

I am using a RadEditor with ContentAreaMode set to DIV. I am using IE 11 . The page is a simple one contains

1. ScriptManager
2. An update panel
3. A RadEditor with ContentAreaMode inside the previously addded UpdatePanel
4. A Button which causes a postback inside the same update panel
5. A dropdownlist with items inside with its autopostback property set to true.

Once the page is rendered the page consists of RadEditor with button and a dropdown . There is no scroll bar on the page yet . So click on the button a postback is caused and NO FOCUS IS SET TO THE RADEDITOR .

Now, Add a few `<br />` before the Button and the DropDown so that we now get a scrollbar on the page . Move to the bottom of the page and select on a button or change the dropdown index so that a postback is caused . 
On Postback we now see that the RadEditor automatically sets focus to its self.

This can be reproducible even in the Demo site
[RADEditor ContentAreaMode="DIV"](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/contentareamodediv/defaultcs.aspx) To reproduce the error on the demo site please follow as described in the document [RADEDITOR.docx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByZhH8S_aNPpT0ZraWZZVnNNRW8/edit?usp=sharing) issue.

The same when tried in Chrome works just fine and the scroll position of the browser is not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick look at their forums and it seems to be an issue they are working on: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/763670-radeditor-contentareamode-div-automatically-sets-focus-on-postback-ie.aspx
Who knows, this may even be your thread :)